# How to use Apache Commons IO with Java

Tags: java, class, program-entry-point, apache-commons

I have a question about Apache Commons IO with Java.

The excercice is to read a text file without using Commons IO, and then using it.

For the first one, my code is this, and this works:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadBook {
private Scanner line;
public void openFile(){
    try{
        line= new Scanner(new File("books.txt"));
    }
catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("File not found");
}
}

public void readFile() {
    while (line.hasNext()) {
    String book = line.next();
    System.out.println(book);
    }
}
    public void closeFile(){
         line.close();
    }

}
```

and the **main** class:

```
public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ReadBook book = new ReadBook();
        book.openFile();
        book.readFile();
        book.closeFile();
    }
}
```

The teacher gave us this class, and now we are supposed to do the same thing with the Apache Commons IO library.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

public class Utf8File {

    public static String loadFileIntoString(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        return IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8");
    }

    public static void saveStringIntoFile(String filePath, String content) throws IOException {
        File f = new File(filePath);
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, content, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

I was wondering, do you know how to do it?

Last time I programmed with Java was one year ago hahaha so it is a little bit far away in my memory :O

This is the first homework to do (today was the first class).

I hope someone can help me :)

Thanks!

Comment: https://o7planning.org/en/10141/java-commons-io-tutorial#a9398
I found this and it helps but I don't understand how to do it with a file in my repertory :O!

Comment: I just don't understand how to use the commons io library. I was wondering if someone can explain it to me, and then I can understand and do my homework

Comment: Well, in the class your teacher gave you, the commons io library is already used. All you should IMHO do, is to call the methods, your teacher already gave you. By calling "loadFileIntoString" you are doing exactly that, read a file an put it into a string. Where is your problem really?

Comment: It says error :O public class UTF8 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
           String loadFileIntoString("books.txt");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}